# SlickGrid Angular issue with width of draggable row grouping when you freeze the column

Tags: angular, slickgrid, angular-slickgrid

I have used draggable grouping and column freeze feature of Angular SlickGrid. The width of row group shrinks if any column is freezed.

[SlickGrid Demo]https://ghiscoding.github.io/angular-slickgrid-demos/#/draggrouping

[image: Draggable grouping width Issue]

I had found one more issue.
Steps to reproduce :

1. Freeze the first column
2. Drag any column for grouping.
3. Remove the column from grouping panel
4. You will still be able to see only one column
   [image: Even after ungrouping it shows only one column]

Comment: @ghiscoding Can you help me with this issue ?

Comment: Known issue in the SlickGrid core lib, you can't use Frozen & Grouping together, see this SlickGrid [issue](https://github.com/6pac/SlickGrid/issues/443)... this is a core lib issue, nothing to do in Angular-Slickgrid itself

Comment: if someone can fix the issue that would be great, this is an Open Source lib and hopefully someone else can contribute in fixing it